# How to pass data from view controller to a navigation controller and then to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have data from a view controller I want to pass another view controller, but I have it set to present modally, so I have a navigation controller between them. How do I pass data from the first view controller through the navigation controller to the second view controller?

I have this code in the first view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "presentPopup"
    {
        let destViewController = segue.destination as! NavigationViewController
        destViewController.myData2 = myData
    }
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

Then this code in the navigation controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    destViewController.myData3 = myData2
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: you don't need to write code in navigationviewcontroller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift pass data through navigation controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369412/swift-pass-data-through-navigation-controller)

Comment: check the link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-passing-data-between-controllers-in-swift--cms-27151

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this in First ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "presentPopup"
    {
        let destViewController = segue.destination as! NavigationViewController
        let secondViewcontroller = destViewController.viewcontrollers.first as! SecondViewcontroller
        secondViewcontroller.myData2 = myData
    }
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

Comment: It says value of NavigationViewController has no member 'first'

Comment: oh sorry forgot viewcontrollers. Please my code again. i just updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 viewControllers, `firstViewController` and `secondViewController` in storyBoard, you make segue between them.

In `firstViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "presentPopup" {
        let destViewController = segue.destination as! secondViewController
        destViewController.myData2 = myData
    }     
}
```

In `secondViewController` declare:

```
var myData2: [same type with myData]? // now you can use myData2
```

**After `perfomeSegue()`, the `myData2` will have value.**

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work, since the segue is connected to the navigation view controller between the two view controllers.